# Comparing 'ita' and 'sic'

Tags: classical-latin, word-comparison

Both *ita* and *sic* mean roughly "so" or "in such way".
I know they are not identical and I have a relatively good feeling of their respective meanings, but I couldn't quite put my finger on the difference.

Could someone summarize what the main differences and similarities are?
What are some example cases where one is appropriate but not the other?

Answer (score 3):

1. Both *ita* and *sic* are used in comparatives:

   - ita... ut, sicut
   - sic... ut, velut

For example : *Ut sementem fecĕris, ita metes*. (Cic.)

2. They are also used with the subjunctive in consecutive (result) clauses:

   - *Atticus sic Graece loquebatur, ut Athenis natus videretur*. (Nep.)
   - *Non sum ita hebes ut istud dicam*

The adverbs which anticipate result clauses are not entirely interchangeable. "Sic" is used primarily to qualify verbs: 
- Id sic dixit ut..
- sic Plinius narrat

*ita* can qualify verbs, adjectives or other adverbs:

- Via erat tam ita longa ut..
- Id ita fecit ut..